# Automatic change of keyboard language in a worksheet in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard, vba, language, visual-basic

In Microsoft Excel, and using ***visual basic***, how to set a default language for different columns? For example, columns A & C should be set to English by default and columns B & D to Persian. Considering that, changing the keyboard language manually when the number of input words in a sheet is very large, it will be a time-consuming task.